# Break a loop animation (Make Cyclic) to start a new one

Tags: animation, keyframes, looping

I've used the 'Make Cyclic' to loop these keyframes (image below). So, I want to break the loop at a certain time to do a new animation (insert another kf to do a different thing than the loop does). Any help how to do this?

[image: loop]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you will have to do it by the NLA Editor: push your first animation in the NLA Editor (down arrow), open the N menu of the NLA Editor > Animation Tab > Action Clip > Playback Settings > Repeat as much as you want, come back to the Dopesheet in Action Editor mode, create your second animation, then push it in the NLA Editor, by default it will appear on a second track above the first one, then move the clip of this second animation where you want it to interrupt your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use the curve editor window.

Instead of using Extrapolation to create a cycle, create a Modifier. Set it to cycles. There you can control how many cycles you want, or use Restrict Frame Range for precise control of the start and end frames for the cycle.

[image]